# System.InvalidCastException: 'Operator '&' is not defined for string "values('41611027," and type 'DataRowView'.'

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

```
        conexion.Open()
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
        cmd.Connection = conexion
        Dim Agregar As String
        Dim fec As Date = Fecha.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
        Dim fac As Date = FechaC.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
        Agregar = "insert into cita (nCuenta, Categoria, Fecha, FechaC, Estado, Usuario)"
        Agregar += "values('" & nCuenta.Text & "," & Categoria.SelectedItem & "','" & fec & "','" & fac & "','" & Estado.SelectedItem
        Agregar += "','" & Usuario.Text & "')"
        cmd.CommandText = Agregar
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Guardado Con Exito")
        Limpiar()
        conexion.Close()
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema con tu consulta es que la propiedad `SelectedItem` no es un `string`, si no un `DataRowView`. Primero debes castear esa propiedad a su tipo real y despues obtener la columna que te interesa (en este ejemplo uso la 0, en tu caso la que necesites)

Por otro lado **nunca** generes tu query usando concatenacion de strings. Utiliza consultas parametrizadas o tu código estará expuesto a la Inyección de SQL. Tu código debe quedar mas o menos asi:

```
'Convertimos los "SelectedItem" a su tipo real,DataRowView
Dim cat As DataRowView = TryCast(Categoria.SelectedItem, DataRowView)
Dim estad As DataRowView = TryCast(Estado.SelectedItem, DataRowView)

Agregar = "insert into cita (nCuenta, Categoria, Fecha, FechaC, Estado, Usuario)"
Agregar += " values(@nCuenta,@Categoria,@fecha,@fechac,@estado,@usuario)"
cmd.CommandText = Agregar
cmd.Parameters.Add("@nCuenta", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = nCuenta.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Categoria", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cat.Item(0).ToString()
cmd.Parameters.Add("@fecha", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = fec
cmd.Parameters.Add("@fechac", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = fac
cmd.Parameters.Add("@estado", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = estad.Item(0).ToString()
cmd.Parameters.Add("@usuario", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Usuario.Text
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Hay otra opcion. Si en tu `ComboBox` configuraste la propiedad `ValueMember`, lo que debes hacer es sustituir `SelectedItem` por `SelectedValue.ToString()`.